# undefined symbol: rmpd_util_str_to_d -

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

During working with gem 'tux' I receive the following error:

```
2: from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
1: from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:130:in `rescue in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ripl-rack-0.2.1/lib/ripl/rack.rb:38:in `eval': /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bigdecimal-1.4.2/lib/bigdecimal/util.so: undefined symbol: rmpd_util_str_to_d - /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bigdecimal-1.4.2/lib/bigdecimal/util.so (LoadError)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Specify/change the version of `bigdecimal` gem in your gemfile:

```rb
gem 'bigdecimal', '1.3.5'
```

Then do `$ bundle install`

Version 1.3.5 is compatible with Ruby 2.5.0

(and other versions have problems, see: https://github.com/ruby/bigdecimal/issues/127)

Answer (score 0):

Try `gem install bigdecimal`.

Even if it's already in your gem list. I tried everything under the sun to correct this error and this was the only thing that worked for me. It shouldn't have made a difference, but it did for me. I hope this info. helps someone.